# HTML Form target to a iframe is not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

```
<form method="post" name="ImportExcel" id="ImportExcel" action="ExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="iframeTarget">
    <input type="file" name="fileUploaded" id="fileUploaded" style="width:325px;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<iframe style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid #000000;" name="iframeTarget" id="iframTarget">
</iframe>
```

I am using Struts2 framework...
On submitting the form the response json is downloading in the browser. I expect the result json to be placed in the iframe...
So the target to the iframe is not working in IE11...
Please help me out

Comment: code you posted is fine. problem is elsewhere. post full code.

Comment: the problem was with the return type.... earlier it was json and changed it to text/html... in the struts.xml

Comment: Hey @user3401747, I have the exact same problem. I tried with response type `JSON` and `text/html` but no luck. When I try the code on IE11, it asks to download the file with the json response.